# Missing option to select existing workflow in Sharepoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have installed Sharepoint Designer 2013 and attempted to create a List Workflow. On my Sharepoint site, I have already created two workflows, but there were no options to select either of them in Sharepoint Designer 2013. How can I fix this? Below is a screenshot:
[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SharePoint 2010 workflows that you are attempting to start in your workflow will need the option "Allow this workflow to be manually started" enabled. You can find this option on the settings page for those workflows under Start Options.